# Retrieve username from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've been trying to retrieve the username for a certain user from a user object in Parse. One of the queries i tried to to that with looks like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: userId!)

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        for object in objects! {
            self.username.text = String(object["username"])
        }
      } 
}
```

Is there another way to do this? I'm really new to working with Parse and I really haven't found a way to make this work yet..

Comment: Possible, guessing that `username` is a `UILabel`, you want to update it in main queue...

Answer (score 0):

When querying the user table, use PFUser.query() to construct your query rather than PFQuery(className: "User")

```
let query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("objectId",equalTo: userId!)

query.findFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{(object,error)->Void in
    if error == nil{
        if let user = object as? PFUser{
            self.username.text = user.username;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.